# How to get class and method names in dll file?

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

For example i have test.dll file. File contains public class Class1, in class public void execute(). How to get names of this class and method?

Comment: [Reflection in .NET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection)

Comment: Listing types and methods are easy. However, you will need to load the library first or reference it. Also, consider reading [ask] and spending more time on your questions to be concise and answerable and useful to future readers

Comment: We can use dotpeek tool to fetch the mentioned details from the dll.

Answer (score 2):

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(path);
Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();
```

Comment: var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.LoadFile(path);
Type[] types = assembly.GetTypes();                                   It gives me ClassLib.Class1 but how i can get Class1 and Execute

Comment: you can iterate all types in this array and for each type you can call something like `var executeMethod = type.GetMethod("Execute"); if (executeMethod != null) ....`.